# there are n^2 pieces, but this is not the answer right? I'll be glad if someone can help me with this.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In the game of dominos, each piece is marked with two numbers. The pieces are symmetrical so that the number pair is not ordered (e.g., (6,2) = (2,6)).How many diﬀerent pieces can be formed using the numbers 1,2,...,n

Answer (score 1):

The number having two equal values is $n,$ namely from $(1,1)$ to $(n,n).$ The number having two unequal values would be $\binom{n}{2},$ i.e. $n(n-1)/2$ since order doesn't matter. So total is $n+\binom{n}{2}.$